# Magento 1.9.4.3 Custom Column Filter not working

Tags: module, magento-1, custom, order-grid

I have a custom column on my sales order grid showing the ordered items sku's. Done by following the guide [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/). It worked well in previous versions but no longer does work correctly in 1.9.4.3.

When I go to filter the column by any given sky, I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'skus' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
>    INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON `sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id WHERE (`skus` LIKE '%tst%')

Backtracing this, the query is from here:

```
    public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();

    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order') {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)");

        $havingCondition = $countSelect->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
        if (count($havingCondition)) {
            $countSelect->where(
                str_replace("group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ')", 'sales_flat_order_item.sku', $havingCondition[0])
            );

        }
    }

    return $countSelect;
}
```

In order to try rectify this I added `'filter_index' => 'sku',` to my addColumnAfter, via a helper function.

This has fixed the above SQL error, but I am now faced with the below issue(s):

Filtering by multiple skus returns no result. i.e,

> Filter by `x,z`, even if order has say sku's `x,c,v,z,y`, no result returned.

Also, Filtered result shows only the sku I am filtering by. i.e,

> Filter by `x`, will only show `x` sku in the column even if the order has say items `x, y and z`.

How would I get it to work so the sku column shows all skus on the order when filtering and multiple sku filter?

My filter callback:

```
public function filterSkus($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->having(
        "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");
    return $collection;
}
```

The helper function:

```
 public function getSkusColumnParams()
{
    return array(
        'header' => 'SKUs',
        'index' => 'skus',
        'filter_index' => 'sku',
        'type' => 'text',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array(Mage::getSingleton('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_model_observer'), 'filterSkus'),
    );
}
```

Config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Atwix_ExtendedGrid>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Atwix_ExtendedGrid>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <atwix_extendedgrid>
            <class>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block</class>
        </atwix_extendedgrid>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <atwix_extendedgrid>
            <class>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Helper</class>
        </atwix_extendedgrid>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <atwix_extendedgrid>
            <class>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model</class>
        </atwix_extendedgrid>
        <sales_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <order_grid_collection>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Resource_Sales_Order_Grid_Collection</order_grid_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </sales_resource>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <atwix_exgrid>
                    <model>atwix_extendedgrid/observer</model>
                    <method>salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                </atwix_exgrid>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </events>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <atwix_extendedgrid>
                <file>atwix/extendedgrid.xml</file>
            </atwix_extendedgrid>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Did you solve this we have the same error where `filter_condition_callback` is not respected in 1 grid ... M1 tries to filter by an EAV column that does not exist .. and hence we see an error

Comment: @snh_nl I didn't truly resolve the issue. But, adding 'filter_index' will fix it

Comment: This will work only for native attributes

Answer (score 0):

There was a code breaking change

Read

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/882

And apply

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/887

Please mark as the answer if correct

Comment: sorry I cannot see the fix on the second link. Can you please add here?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/887/commits/9b00daf4a50edba1a8beabe10acf26e5c820ff46

Comment: Never a good idea to touch any core code.

Comment: Unless a github fork

Answer (score 0):

snh_nl isn't wrong, but it's just as easy to solve this problem without modifying core code.

If you add your callback function to a custom block class that extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid, that will satisfy the new condition recently added by Magento in the function `_addColumnFilterToCollection($column)` in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php`

OLD core code:

`if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {`

NEW core code added in 1.9.4.3:

`if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback() && $column->getFilterConditionCallback()[0] instanceof self) {`

---

So in your case, create
`app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Block/Widget/Grid.php`

```
class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {
    public function filterSkus($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->having(
            "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

And modify the callback in your helper function:

```
public function getSkusColumnParams()
{
    return array(
        'header' => 'SKUs',
        'index' => 'skus',
        'filter_index' => 'sku',
        'type' => 'text',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array(Mage::getBlockSingleton('atwix_extendedgrid/widget_grid'), 'filterSkus'),
    );
}
```

Comment: I will duly try this.